# Which tower consumptions benefit a Temple of the Monkey God, and how, exactly?

Tags: bloons-td-5

I'd like to know exactly which towers benefit a Temple of the Monkey God and how? Also, do the upgrades on those towers improve the benefit?

Finally, does one TMG consuming another TMG also improve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sacrifices to the Temple are a complex topic, so I suggest [reading this wiki page](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_Monkey_God/Sacrifices) to get the full picture.

The basic rules are:

- Up to 30,000 worth of Ice Towers can be sacrificed to give additional ice power
- Up to 30,000 worth of Glue Towers can be sacrificed to give additional glue power
- Up to 30,000 worth of Monkey Apprentice towers can be sacrificed for additional tornado power
- Up to 30,000 worth of bomb/mortar towers can be sacrificed for additional missile power
- Up to 30,000 worth of other towers (including other temples) for additional dart or blade explosion power

You can also sacrifice Monkey Villages to get the benefit of the village applied to the Temple itself.

The radius of the sacrifice region is related to the radius of the tower, so boosting the tower radius (ie, with a monkey village) will cause the temple to absorb towers from further away - for better or for worse.

Answer (score 2):

Ice, Glue, Monkey Apprentice, Bomb and Mortar towers have special effects. They all give some power related to what they do individually, Apprentice towers give better tornadoes, Bomb/Mortar gives better missile attacks etc. The saw blade attacks which seem like they would be from the tack shooter are actually affected by any kind of tower except the 5 previously mentioned. The sun attacks are affected by any kind of tower including the 5 previously mentioned. And consuming a TMG will only improve the saw attacks, as it is not counted as the different types that are included in it.